# How to change text direction of textbox on radio button click?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this small piece of code and I can't resolve the problem of direction. I have a text field with constant direction of left. I have 2 radio buttons, "Right" and "Left". When I click "Right", it shows the value of "Right" radio button, and same with "Left". I want to have that when I click "Right", the text shows on the right side of the text field with `dir="rtl"`, and when "Left" is clicked, `dir="ltr"`.

Here is the code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[name="radio-1"]').on('change', function() {
    $('input[name="direction"]').val($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```css
.toggler {
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
.toggler2 {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <legend>Choose direction:</legend>
  <input type="radio" class="click" name="radio-1" id="radio-1" value="Right">
  <label for="radio-1">Right</label>
  <input type="radio" class="click" name="radio-1" id="radio-2" value="Left">
  <label for="radio-2">Left</label>
  <div class="toggler2">
    <input type="text" name="direction">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Working code: https://jsfiddle.net/pk0vnkLn/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this by setting the `dir` attribute on the element based on the checked option:

```
$('input[name="radio-1"]').on('change', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('input[name="direction"]').val(value).attr('dir', value == 'Right' ? 'rtl' : 'ltr');
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pk0vnkLn/2/)

Comment: Quick shot...We did just saw the ball only after touch the four line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Got what i wanted, but still didn't fixed my problem, with what i am working on like 5 days. Now it is time to make question about it, but don't know if i can. Still thank you for direction change ;)